# SQL query with row number and data cleaning there is no validation

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have "prices" table with this data:

| id | start_date | end_date | paid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 787 | 1/1/2022 | 1/15/2022 | 100 |
| 787 | 1/15/2022 | 1/22/2022 | 100,000 |
| 787 | 1/22/2022 | 2/25/2022 | 115,000 |
| 787 | 2/25/2022 | 2/28/2022 | 14,000 |
| 787 | 2/28/2022 | 3/05/2022 | 122,000 |
| 787 | 3/05/2022 | 3/09/2022 | 120 |
| 423 | 1/25/2022 | 2/25/2022 | 1 |
| 423 | 2/25/2022 | 2/28/2022 | 7,500,000 |
| 423 | 3/19/2022 | 3/22/2022 | 7,200,000 |
| 423 | 3/25/2022 | 3/29/2022 | 1,111,111,111 |
| 423 | 4/13/2022 | 4/26/2022 | 999,999,999,999 |
| 423 | 4/26/2022 | 4/28/2022 | 999,999,999,99 |
| 423 | 4/28/2022 | 5/09/2022 | 7,100,000 |
| 423 | 5/09/2022 | 5/22/2022 | 666,666,666,666 |

I want to stay just with one raw per **id** with start date ASC and end_date DESC
but the most important is if I have a small number or bigger then others like the price **is not between** 30% or -30% from the following price take me the last/after price and then its will be the "real" price.
my output:

| id | start_date | end_date | first_paid | last_paid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 787 | 1/1/2022 | 3/09/2022 | 100,000 | 122,000 |
| 423 | 1/25/2022 | 5/22/2022 | 7,500,000 | 7,100,000 |

I created this query but it's with all numbers including the "fake" numbers and I want to clean the "fake" numbers:

```
select a.id, b.start_date, a.end_date, b.paid as first_paid, a.price as last_paid
from(
select id, start_date, end_date, paid 
from (
    select *, 
        row_number() over(partition by id order by end_date desc) rn
    from "prices" 
)
where rn = 1) as a 
left join 
(select id, start_date, end_date, paid
from(
select id, start_date, end_date, paid 
from (
    select *, 
        row_number() over(partition by id order by start_date) rn
    from "prices" 
)
where rn = 1)) as b 
on a.id = b.id
```

**if someone has a good idea or solution and it will be in presto syntax it will be amazing.**

thanks all.

Comment: What is "real price" and how it is determined?

Comment: *But the most important If I have numbers smaller or bigger than others then…* : What is the actual rule here to ignore a value?

Comment: @Guru Stron
I was editing my commit :)

Comment: @GMB I was editing my commit :)

Answer (score 0):

I do hope your explanation was received correctly..

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/VHGflVN1) with some explanations on what is done to get this:

```sql
SELECT 
  x.id, 
  x.start_date,
  x.end_date,
  min(x.first_paid) as first_paid,
  max(x.last_paid) as last_paid
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT 
   id,
   min(start_date) over (partition by id) as start_date,
   max(end_date) over (partition by id) as end_date,
   first_value(paid) over (partition by id order by start_date) as first_paid,
   last_value(paid) over (partition by id order by end_date) as last_paid
FROM (
    SELECT
      id,
      start_date,
      end_date,
      paid as old_paid,
      lag(paid) over (partition by id order by start_date) as previus_paid,
      CASE WHEN abs(((lag(paid) over (partition by id order by start_date))-paid)
         /(lag(paid) over (partition by id order by start_date))) > 30 
       THEN lag(paid) over (partition by id order by start_date)
       ELSE paid END as paid
FROM mytable2 m2 
) m1) x
GROUP BY x.id,x.start_Date,x.end_date
  ;
```

output:

| id | start_date | end_date | first_paid | last_paid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 423 | 2022-01-25 | 2022-05-22 | 1.00 | 99999999999.00 |
| 787 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-03-09 | 100.00 | 122000.00 |

I now see that I must a made a type somewhere, because `100` seems not be correct...

But I will leave that for you to find out where I wen wrong.....

EDIT: You will have to find a smart way to filter the low and high values that you do not want to include.

Something like:

```sql
select * from (
   SELECT
     id,
     paid,
     avg(paid) over (partition by id) as avg1,
     abs((COALESCE(lead(paid) over (partition by id order by paid),min(paid) over (partition by id)) +
      COALESCE(lag(paid) over (partition by id order by paid),max(paid) over (partition by id)) + 
      paid)/3 - paid ) as avg2
   FROM mytable2 m2  
  ) x where x.avg2 < avg1
order by x.id,x.paid
```

output:

| id | paid | avg1 | avg2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 423 | 7100000.00 | 220974947222.000000 | 2333333.000000 |
| 423 | 7200000.00 | 220974947222.000000 | 66666.666666 |
| 423 | 7500000.00 | 220974947222.000000 | 367770370.333333 |
| 423 | 1111111111.00 | 220974947222.000000 | 32595092592.333333 |
| 423 | 99999999999.00 | 220974947222.000000 | 155925925926.333333 |
| 423 | 666666666666.00 | 220974947222.000000 | 77777777778.000000 |
| 787 | 100.00 | 58536.666666 | 40640.000000 |
| 787 | 120.00 | 58536.666666 | 4620.000000 |
| 787 | 14000.00 | 58536.666666 | 24040.000000 |
| 787 | 100000.00 | 58536.666666 | 23666.666667 |
| 787 | 115000.00 | 58536.666666 | 2666.666667 |
| 787 | 122000.00 | 58536.666666 | 42966.666667 |

This filters the `1` and the `999,999,999,999` ....

Comment: Thank you! But it’s a little bit different from the output I wrote, I also don't want to refer to 1 and 99999999999.00

Comment: See; this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/n42QRUks), and find "PERCENTAGE_CHANGE", this should explain why `99999999999.00` is in the results, and for `1.00` I should have checked for `null`....   But I do hope that this stuff did help to find a solution to _YOUR_ problem ?

Comment: unfortunately its not working very well but its really close.
still my first_paid its 1.00 and last_paid 99999999999.00 
@luuk

Comment: Added final thought about how to exclude the min and/org max values...   Good luck with solving your problem!